# C# .NET 3.5: What is Expression<> used for?

Tags: c#, expression

What exactly is Expression<> used for in C#? Are there any scenarios where you would instantiate Expression<>'s yourself as an object? If so, please give an example!

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Expression<T>` is almost entirely used for LINQ, but it doesn't *have* to be. Within LINQ, it's usually used to "capture" the logic expressed in code, but keep it in data. That data can then be examined by the LINQ provider and handled appropriately - e.g. by converting it into SQL. Usually the expression trees in LINQ are created by the compiler from lambda expressions or query expressions - but in other cases it can be handy to use the API directly yourself.

A few examples of other places I've used it and seen it used:

- In [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil), Marc Gravell used it to implement "generic arithmetic" - if a type has the relevant operator, it can be used generically.
- In [UnconstrainedMelody](https://github.com/jskeet/unconstrained-melody) I used it in a similar way to perform operations on flags enums, regardless of their underlying type (which is trickier than you might expect, due to `long` and `ulong` having different ranges)
- In [Visual LINQ](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/02/19/visual-linq-watch-query-expressions-as-they-happen/) I used query expressions to "animate" LINQ, so you can see what's going on. While obviously this is a LINQ usage, it's not the traditional form of translating logic into another form.

Comment: where can i see 'VisualLINQ'?

Answer (score 4):

In terms of LINQ, there are things you can do to create more versatile LINQ queries at runtime than you can purely in lambdas.

I've used `Expression` many times as a micro-compiler, as an alternative to `DynamicMethod` and IL. This approach gets stronger in .NET 4.0 ([as discussed on InfoQ](http://www.infoq.com/articles/expression-compiler)), but even in 3.5 there are *lots* of things you can do (generally based on runtime data; configuration etc):

- [generic operators](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html)
- object cloning
- complex initialization
- [object comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986572/)

I also used it as part of a maths engine for some work I did with Microsoft - i.e. parse a math expression ("(x + 12) * y = z" etc) into an `Expression` tree, compile it and run it.

Another intersting use (illustrated by Jason Bock, [here](http://www.jasonbock.net/jb/Default.aspx?blog=entry.b2ff6b7e47ae41929e38beec4093518e)) is in genetic programming; build your candidates as `Expression` trees, and you have the necessary code to execute them quickly (after `Compile()`), but importantly (for genetic programming), also to swap fragments around.

Comment: Is there anywhere we can see the code you did for Microsoft? I'd really like to see some examples of this kind of thing ..

Comment: I have a copy, but I don't think it would be wise to post it "as is" (it is joint-owned by my employer and Microsoft). I'll try to find time to re-do from inception - it isn't much, I wrote the original on the train on the way to Microsoft's Reading HQ ;-p

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my before & after code in [my answer to another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269967/feeding-an-object-literal-to-ilgenerator/1269972#1269972).

Summary: `Expression<>` greatly simplified the code, made it easier to understand, and even fixed a phantom bug.